# Setup BIOS to network boot to FOG server

Tags: networking, bios, pxe, fog

I have a FOG server installed on my Ubuntu 12.4 OS. The FOG server is setup and running. On the client machine, I am trying to network boot into my FOG server, but it never connects. I can't figure out which PXE ROM option that I should use either, UEFI or Legacy.

Comment: My Motherboard and BIOS is Gigabyte model: GA-Z77X-UD5H

Comment: Where does it fail to connect? Does the box get DHCP on network boot? Does it manage to boot in to anything?

Comment: I don't get the DHCP box. But it does show my Atheros network adapter trying to boot before the BIOS screen comes up. Then after the BIOS, it boots into Windows. It never shows the FOG options screen.

Comment: I really wish I could upload pictures of my BIOS settings. There are lot of settings that involve PXE, and it is rather confusing.

Comment: Do you have DHCP configured to respond to PXE boot requests?

Comment: @Tanner I have FOG configured to my servers DHCP if that is what you mean.

Comment: Nope! Your DHCP server needs to respond to requests with the appropriate information to facilitate a PXE boot. Here's a bit about the [nuts and bolts](http://www.intel.com/support/network/sb/CS-028533.htm) of how it works. How you configure your DHCP server to allow PXE boot depends on what you're using for DHCP.